# Undefined index when trying to see if user exist?

Tags: php, angularjs, eloquent

I get a Undefined index every time i type a keyword,  it shows in the terminal like this.

Basically trying to see if a user exists and then output it the under neath the username input field.

My function works but i guess angular doesn't search through an eloquent database ? i can't wrap my head around getting this work.

thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

(Part of the AuthController.php)

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers\Auth;


use App\Controllers\BaseController;

use App\Auth\Auth;

use App\Models\User;




class AuthController extends BaseController
{

   public function check_user($request, $response)
   {
      $input = $request->getParsedBody();

      $user = new User();


      $myusername = $input['signupusername'];

      $username = filter_var($myusername, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      if(User::where('username', '=', $myusername)->exists()) {

            return "username already taken";
      }
   }
```

**Main.js**

```
angular.module('usernameScope.directive', [])
.directive('userExist', function ($http, $q){

   return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.userExist = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                return $http.post('/auth/check_user', {username: viewValue})
                    .then(
                     function(response) {
                             if (!response.data.status) {
                                  return $q.reject(); 
                                 //Server will give me a  notify if it exist or not. I will throw a error If it exist with "reject"
                             }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    };


});
```

Comment: Looks like `signupusername` var is not set / available.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is due to this line:

```
$input = $request->getParsedBody();
```

Change this line to:

```
$input = $request->all();
```

or use this

```
$myusername = $request->input('signupusername');
```

Comment: now i get 
`angular.min.js:108 POST http://localhost:8080/auth/check_user 500 (Internal Server Error)`